# ANSI SQL question

Tags: sql

I have a table which has fields (id, parent_id, name, created_at). I want to write a query to select id, name, created_at, parent_created_at. The 'parent_created_at' is the 'created_at' field for the records matching parent (if it has one - i.e. the records parent_id >0), otherwise the 'parent_created_at' field should be null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Join + ANSI SQL CASE Expression

```
SELECT t.id
       , t.name
       , t.created_at
       , CASE WHEN t.parent_id > 0 THEN p.created_at ELSE NULL END AS parent_created_at 
FROM   Table t
JOIN   Table p
ON     t.id = p.parent_id
```

Comment: Not quite the result I expected:

mysql> select t.id, t.title, t.created_at, u.name, CASE WHEN t.parent_id > 0 then p.created_at ELSE NULL END AS p
arent_created_at from  user u, table t join table p on t.id=p
.parent_id where t.creator_id=u.id;

I have 2 records in table 'table' 1 with parent_ids of 0 and 1 respectively. I expected both rows to display. Only the row with parent_id=0 displays .. ? *scratches head*

Comment: Geez. Instead of scratching your head, how about giving all the details for your two-row table? That should take about 10 seconds, and you won't waste everyone's time. (See my answer for a template on how you might provide this information.)

Comment: @Morpheous and @Svetlozar: (A LEFT OUTER JOIN is all you need, by the way, but it's still common courtesy to give some details.)

Comment: @Steve Kass you are right... I just don't know how is defined "missing parent"... If it is 0 and for some reason there is user with id = 0.... but you are right, my "defense" is useless

Comment: @Svetlozar: Thanks, and thanks to StackOverflow for the forum to clear it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Morpheous,

You only have two rows in your table, so please take the trouble to give all the details! All you tell us is what their parent_ids are, and your query's join condition depends on more than that.

Can you fill in the ... below so we know the ***full*** details?

```
CREATE TABLE t(...
INSERT INTO t VALUES (...
INSERT INTO t VALUES (...
```